# Error while getting re-arrange np.array to float64 data during calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am reading from a variable "RF" from CSV file and then I have an "array" data. I want to put some equation between both variables. Therefore, I am converting my array dataset into "RF" data format. In my CSV file I have 8 variables but presently I am reading only one variable. When I am executing the code it is giving some error.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import csv
data_df = pd.read_csv('poly2_decpred_juneRF.csv', header=0, nrows=67)
y1 = data_df['RF']
y1.head(67)

finalpred1=[2.22, 2.33, 3.33, 1.21, 2.22, 2.33, 3.33, 1.21, 2.22, 2.33, 3.33, 1.21, 2.22, 2.33, 3.33, 1.21, 2.33]
s = pd.Series(finalpred1, name='RF')
print(s)
y111=y1[50:67]
print(y111)
diff = ((y111-s)/y111)*100
print(diff)
```

The output is coming like this:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
12   NaN
13   NaN
14   NaN
15   NaN
16   NaN
50   NaN
51   NaN
52   NaN
53   NaN
54   NaN
55   NaN
56   NaN
57   NaN
58   NaN
59   NaN
60   NaN
61   NaN
62   NaN
63   NaN
64   NaN
65   NaN
66   NaN
Name: RF, dtype: float64
```

The CSV dataset is given in this format:

```
RF,Nino,IOD,SOI,NAO,TNA,TSA,MEI
103.77,-1.04,0.20,2.70,-1.02,0.18,-0.92,-1.26
83.99,0.71,0.16,-1.70,1.32,-0.07,0.00,0.48
86.97,-0.55,0.21,-1.30,-0.43,0.55,-0.14,-0.12
152.58,0.15,0.11,-1.00,-0.47,0.17,-0.41,0.32
230.83,-0.79,0.18,0.60,0.69,-0.30,-0.23,-1.11
223.45,-1.52,-0.06,-0.50,0.17,0.30,-0.57,-1.88
118.26,-0.58,0.08,1.50,0.10,0.05,-0.49,-1.02
93.58,1.18,-0.02,-0.60,0.12,0.17,-0.16,1.25
..........................................
132.30,2.56,0.49,0.10,2.24,0.42,0.70,2.11
110.00,-0.51,-0.07,0.40,0.48,0.52,0.67,-0.12
```

Total rows are 67:
Please help me out

Comment: Are you even aware of the tags that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use instead `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(finalpred1, name='RF')
```

`numpy array`:

```
s = np.array(finalpred1)
```

because there are different index values and not match, so output are `NaN`s

But better is filter only `RF` column and skip first `50` rows:

```
s = pd.read_csv('poly2_decpred_juneRF.csv', 
                header=0, 
                nrows=17, 
                skiprows=range(1, 50), 
                usecols=['RF'])
```